# How to avoid using dynamic variables / a billion if statements in Java?

Tags: java

So, since dynamic variables aren't a thing in Java, and if statements will be horribly unwieldy, was looking for help converting this code block into a more concise one.

I looked into hashmaps, and they just didn't seem quite right, it's highly likely I was misunderstanding them though.

```
public String m1 = "Name1";
public String m1ip = "192.1.1.1";
public String m2 = "Name2";
public String m2ip = "192.1.1.1";
public String req;
public String reqip;
```

... snip some code...

```
if (requestedMachine == 1)
{ req = m1; reqip = m1ip;}
else if (requestedMachine == 2)
{ req = m2; reqip = m2ip;}
else if (requestedMachine == 3)
{ req = m3; reqip = m3ip;}
else if (requestedMachine == 4)
{ req = m4; reqip = m4ip;}
else if (requestedMachine == 5)
{ req = m5; reqip = m5ip;}
```

requestedMachine is going to be an integer, that defines which values should be assigned to req & reqip.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not a straightforward array?

Comment: It'd have to be multidimensional, right? To hold the data for name + IP. And I'm not at all confident implementing that, if I'm honest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a Machine class, containing a `name` and an `ip` field. Create an array of Machine. Access the machine located at the index `requestedMachine` (or `requestedMachine - 1` if the number starts at 1):

```
Machine[] machines = new Machine[] {
    new Machine("Name1", "192.1.1.1"),
    new Machine("Name2", "192.1.1.1"),
    ...
}
...

Machine machine = machines[requestedMachine - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

First, create a Machine class:

```
class Machine {
    String name;
    String ip;
    //Constructor, getters, setters etc omitted
}
```

Initialize an array of Machines:

```
Machine[] machines = ... //initialize them with values
```

Get the machine corresponding to `requestedMachine`:

```
Machine myMachine = machines[requestedMachine];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great candidate for an enum:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java EnumDeltaXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class EnumDeltaXmpl  {
  public static final void main(String[] ingo_red)  {
     test(MachineAction.ONE);
     test(MachineAction.TWO);
     test(MachineAction.THREE);
     test(MachineAction.FOUR);
  }
  private static final void test(MachineAction m_a)  {
     System.out.println("MachineAction." + m_a + ": name=" + m_a.sName + ", ip=" + m_a.sIP + "");
  }
}

enum MachineAction  {
   ONE("Name1", "192.1.1.1"),
   TWO("Name2", "292.2.2.2"),
   THREE("Name3", "392.3.3.3"),
   FOUR("Name4", "492.4.4.4"),
   FIVE("Name5", "592.5.5.5");

   public final String sName;
   public final String sIP;

   private MachineAction(String s_name, String s_ip)  {
      sName = s_name;
      sIP = s_ip;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java EnumDeltaXmpl
MachineAction.ONE: name=Name1, ip=192.1.1.1
MachineAction.TWO: name=Name2, ip=292.2.2.2
MachineAction.THREE: name=Name3, ip=392.3.3.3
MachineAction.FOUR: name=Name4, ip=492.4.4.4
```

Comment: Ouch. Why don't you respect the naming conventions? All these `s_` and `m_` make the code quite hard to read. Even Microsoft has abandoned this ugly hungarian notation.

Comment: I like Hungarian notation. I prefer `iRequestedMachine`, over `requestedMachine`, to know at a glance that it's an int, and not a `Machine` object. I'd actually choose `idxMachine` to make it clear it's an index, which is not obvious until you use it that way: `machines[requestedMachine]`. I use underscore to indicate a function parameter, which I also think makes the code clearer. You know at a glance where it originates. I haven't seen official documentation denouncing Hungarian notation or using underscores in this way.

Comment: Then use requestedMachineIndex, and not iMachine or idxMachine. That is readable, pronounceable, and respects the Java naming conventions. If you can't tell at a glance where a local variable originated, it means your methods are too long and should be refactored. Not respecting the Java naming conventions will piss off all your coworkers.

Comment: I like the `requestedMachineIndex` idea. I'll look for some more information on naming conventions. I'm not stuck on doing it my way, it's the "at a glance" philosophy that's important to me. The "not pissing off co-workers" is not a bad philosophy either.

Answer (score 0):

Thee best choice you have is to build an array of machines with IP, Name etc..then you only need to find the machine required into the array.

```
public class Machine(){
private String name, ip;
public Machine(String name, String ip){
   this.name=name;
   // You can check a valid ip
   this.ip=ip;
}}


public class Machines(){
private Machine[] machines;
private int number_of_machines;
public Machines(){
  //define number_of_machines for your array and length of itself
}}
main()
Machine[] Machines = new Machine[number_of_machines];
Machine m1 = new Machine(String name, String ip);
.
.
.
Machine mn = new Machine(String name, String ip);
int number=5;
for(int i=0; i<number_of_machines; i++){
   if (machines[number]<number_of_machines){
      System.out.println("There is no machine with that number");
   }else if (machines[number]==number_of_machines-1){
      System.out.println("That is the choosen machine");
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If your id values are not necessarily integers or if they are not a continuous sequence from 0 forward, you could also use a HashMap. Something like

```
HashMap<Integer, Machine> machines = new HashMap<>();
machines.put(1, machine1);
machines.put(7, machine7);
...
```

to get the desired value

```
Machine machine7 = machines.get(7);
```

You can replace the key with a String or whatever you like if needed. Your id values also do not need to go 0,1,2,3,4,5, ... as they need to if you are going with an array.